# Sorting and then filtering JSON data into separate components

Tags: reactjs, filter, leaflet, components, react-leaflet

I'm trying to work out the logic and I'm a little stuck.  I have an array of objects that look like this.

```
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Mole's Town",
        "lat": 33,
        "lng": 18.5,
        "type": "village"
    }
```

There are several different types, nine total.  Village, Town, City etc.  I am trying to make a  component for each of these nine types, and then filter all the objects that match that certain type into the appropriate LayerControl group.

This is what I have so far, but this just renders the Marker component but doesn't take into account the type.

```
  const stuff = data.map((location) =>
        <Marker key={location.id} position={[location.lat, location.lng]} icon= 
           {locationIcon}>
          <Tooltip permanent direction="bottom" opacity={.6}>
            {location.name}
          </Tooltip>
        </Marker>
      )
```

Comment: Do you want to switch by type the Marker component, tooltip, etc or do you want to have a component which englobes those ones?

Comment: Just a component that encases each type.  So all Markers with type 'city' would be in a LayerControl component, all Markers with type 'village' would go into a seperate LayerControl component etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to find all the unique types in your array :

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Mole's Town",
        "lat": 15,
        "lng": 18.5,
        "type": "village"
    },
    {
        "id": 783,
        "name": "Mole's Town",
        "lat": 3,
        "lng": 18.5,
        "type": "village"
    },
    {
        "id": 75,
        "name": "Mole's Town",
        "lat": 33,
        "lng": 8.55,
        "type": "town"
    },
    {
        "id": 43,
        "name": "Mole's Town",
        "lat": 33,
        "lng": 15,
        "type": "city"
    },
    {
        "id": 443,
        "name": "Mole's Town",
        "lat": 35,
        "lng": 725,
        "type": "city"
    },
    {
        "id": 4543,
        "name": "Mole's Town",
        "lat": 76,
        "lng": 2,
        "type": "city"
    }
]

const types = [...new Set(data.map(loc => loc.type))]

console.log(types)
```

Once you have them, in your render function, map them with your `LayerControl` while filtering every location having the same type and send it as a prop :

```
types.map(type => <LayerControl key={type} locations={data.filter(loc => loc.type === type)}/>)
```

Then in your `LayerControl` render, map every received locations to the code you gave in your question :

```
this.props.locations.map(({id, lat, lng, name}) => //Deconstructing every location to make your code more readable
    <Marker key={id} position={[lat, lng]} icon=
        {locationIcon}>
        <Tooltip permanent direction="bottom" opacity={.6}>
            {name}
        </Tooltip>
    </Marker>
)
```

Comment: Great answer - I forgot about Set.  I need to keep messing with the code as LayersControl is a react-leaflet component and its rendering it nine times on the page, but I think I can figure it out with your guidance here.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey there! I've spent a few hours trying to figure this out but still running into issues.  I posted my code in a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/geeberry/q2xu9kj6/2/

With the top one being my LeafletMap code which is the Parent, and the second window being the Overlay component that should render each LayerGroup (nine total of nine total types).  I really appreciate it!

Comment: I just checked your fiddle quickly. The `render` function of a class component does not receive any props, to access your props, use `this.props`. Also, you put a React js component into the HTML part of JSFiddle

Answer (score 2):

You could create an object to map each type with the corresponding component. Something like this will work:

```
const LayerVillage = ({ position, name }) => (
  <Marker position={position} icon={locationIcon}>
    <TooltipComponent permanent direction="bottom" opacity={0.6}>
      {name}
    </TooltipComponent>
  </Marker>
);

const layerComponentsByType = {
  village: LayerVillage,
  town: LayerTown
};

const stuff = data.map(location => {
  const LayerControl = layerComponentsByType[location.type];
  return (
    <LayerControl
      key={location.id}
      position={[location.lat, location.lng]}
      name={location.name}
    />
  );
});
```

Another possibility is the following:

```
    <LayerControl
      key={location.id}
      {...location}
    />
```

With this way, you would receive the location object key-value pairs as properties.

Also, you could have a default component, because location.type could not be a property of layerComponentsByType:

```
  const LayerControl = layerComponentsByType[location.type] || DefaultLayerControl;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will try and work with this...might need to refactor a bit as <LayersControl /> is an already existing component from the react-leaflet library.